# How did Elle overcome her mental block?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-black-lotus

In the episode *the Doll Hunt*, Elle and the other replicants seem to have some sort of mental block which renders them unable to fight back against the hunters. However, when Hooper is kicking Elle around there's a point where her eyes glow for a second, and suddenly she can whoop Hooper's ass. So what happened to enable Elle to fight? What caused her eyes to glow for that one second?

Answer (score 1):

## Massive series spoilers. Fair warning.

Niander Wallace Jr. was displeased with what his father and his compatriots were doing with replicants so he created Elle to dispose of them. While the other replicants can't fight back, Elle clearly has a set of fighting skills implanted (as we see when Wallace Jr. sends Water Lily, another "black lotus" replicant, to kill Elle).

It's probable that Elle was placed in the Doll Hunt deliberately, with the skills suppressed, in the hopes that she would witness the horrors of the Doll Hunt and awaken. The bank shot was Wallace Jr. hoped she would become driven to kill those who had wronged her and the other replicants (as Wallace Jr. confessed to Joseph).

Comment: Seems like a flawed plan- if a hunter dropped Elle with a lucky shot early on, what would Wallace Jr. do then?

Comment: @Nu'Daq While there's one more episode, my assumption is that a complete kill Doll Hunt would have lead to more of them being made for that. In other words, Wallace Jr would probably have had more opportunities to get a black lotus who wanted to kill the participants.